# How to Merge default database with custom database in MVC Template

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I have searched over internet but nowhere I found the satisfactory answer about how to merge the default database with developer's custom designed database.

i.e. I created a web project using **MVC Template** and I run the application and it created the default database with name `defaultconnection`. Now I need to merge this database with my own database i.e. mydatabase.mdf created in **SQL Server Management Studio**.

So how this is possible to do that, any satisfactory with step by step answer will be highly appreciated and helpful for newbie like me.

Comment: In Visual Studio Ultimate and Premium you can compare and synchronize the data and the schema databese - Tools -> SQL Server -> New Data/Schema Comparison..

Comment: brother vs2013 MVC Template creates default database with name i.e. defaultconnectioin.mdf. and when a developer creates the database according to his application then here is a need to merge both these database so that use can singup and signin using .net security layer and use its custom database too